# My Inbox is flooded with Amazon SES emails "Email DKIM setup FAILURE for... in US East (Ohio) region". how to stop them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My Inbox is flooded with Amazon SES emails "Email DKIM setup FAILURE for... in US East (Ohio)"
We use SES API to monitor the domains so there is no need for these emails, but I can't any settings to disable these emails.
Any idea how to stop these?

Comment: I think they are AWS notification emails and you cannot disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your domain identity in SES? That's done by providing few DNS records in your Route 53. Those records usually look like `5md77k6qtolu611c2mua26erx62vhr25._domainkey.yourdomain.com` and there should be 3 similar ones (with different hash in the beginning).

If you don't have those DNS records (and unverified domain in SES) then follow [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-dkim-easy.html#send-email-authentication-dkim-easy-setup-domain) to verify it, which will hopefully get rid you of those e-mails.

Comment: We have hundreds domains there so we'll always receive those emails. I'm looking for a way to not receive them on the email that's attached to our aws account

Answer (score 0):

You have below options available, see if this will help you.

`UpdateAccountSendingEnabled` Enables or disables email sending across your entire Amazon SES account in the current AWS Region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateAccountSendingEnabled.html

`UpdateConfigurationSetSendingEnabled`
Enables or disables email sending for messages sent using a specific configuration set in a given AWS Region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateConfigurationSetSendingEnabled.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want those emails in the future u can directly put them in the spam folder but if you want them in the future there is an option to disable it here link for setting page :-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateAccountSendingEnabled.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the API **UpdateAccountSendingEnabled** to disable email sending across your entire Amazon SES account in the current AWS Region.
You can use this operation in conjunction with Amazon CloudWatch alarms to temporarily pause email sending across your Amazon SES account in a given AWS Region when reputation metrics (such as your bounce or complaint rates) reach certain thresholds.

For more details you can read the api reference here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateAccountSendingEnabled.html